# mysql database composite key issues

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, database-indexes

We have a database with a data table in it defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
msts BIGINT,
variable_id INT,
p_id INT,
value DOUBLE,
PRIMARY KEY(msts,variable_id,p_id)
);

ALTER TABLE data
ADD    FOREIGN KEY (p_id)
REFERENCES p(id);

ALTER TABLE data
ADD    FOREIGN KEY (variable_id)
REFERENCES variables(id);
```

This table can contain billions of records.

When doing a simple query:

```
SELECT COUNT(msts) from data FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) where (
msts<1535886000000000000 AND msts>1535796060000000000  AND  
variable_id=107  AND p_id=661 );
```

yeilding:

```
+-------------+
| COUNT(msts) |
+-------------+
|       89873 |
+-------------+
1 row in set (42.51 sec)
```

takes 42.51 seconds to count 89873.

Why should it take so long seeing as the primary key should act as a composite index?

This is the explain:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(msts) from data FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) where 
( msts<1535886000000000000 AND msts>1535796060000000000  AND 
variable_id=107  AND plant_id=661 );
```

which gives:

```
rows = 190996998
filtered=0
ref=NULL
type=range
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hint: range scan

Comment: Thanks Lukasz any chance of describing in code how it should be done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query, rewritten to change the order of the where clauses, is this.

```
SELECT COUNT(msts) 
  from data 
 where variable_id=107 
   and p_id=661
   and msts>1535796060000000000
   and msts<1535886000000000000;
```

It contains two equality matches, on variable_id and p_id. It then contains a range filter on msts.  Therefore, you need an index on the `(variable_id, p_id, msts)` columns *in that order* to help satisfy your query quickly.

Why? You can think of MySQL indexes as sorted in order. To satisfy your query, MySQL random-accesses the index to the first eligible item. It then scans it sequentially until the last item. That's called an index range scan.

Your pre-existing index lists msts first. That means your index can't be scanned sequentially, because each msts value in the index potentially has lots of values of the other two columns.

**Pro tip 1:**  Use `COUNT(*)` when you can instead of `COUNT(column)`. The second one is slower because it must omit any column values that are NULL. The first one just counts them all.

**Pro tip 2:** Extra single column indexes are not useful unless they help speed up a specific query.

**Pro tip 3:** Forcing the use of an index is almost always a bad choice.

**Pro tip 4:** Read https://use-the-index-luke.com/

**Edit**: You asked how to do the conversion.

If your table does not yet contain many millions of rows, just change the primary key definition like this.

```
ALTER TABLE data 
       DROP PRIMARY KEY, 
       ADD PRIMARY KEY (variable_id, p_id, msts);
```

If it does contain billions of rows already, you probably should create a new table, with the correct definition, into which to copy your existing table. Then copy  your data. Then rename the old table to `data_old` or something, and rename the new table to `data`.  This may be a complex task involving batches of data; if you can't figure it out ask another question.

Comment: Thanks O. Jones. So would this involve changing the ordering in the primary key to: (variable_id, p_id, msts)? I'll give it a go! Many thanks!

Comment: @kitt91 - Plan A rearrange the PK..  Plan B add a secondary index with those 3 columns.  Either is time-consuming on a billion rows.  'B' will consume a bunch of extra disk space.  Another [_index cookbook_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: @O.Jones - thanks this worked! Considerable speed improvement to a fraction of a second! Thanks again